# In P2PKH Multisig Transactions, what is the address?

Tags: multi-signature

In P2SH transactions, the address is the hash of the redeemScript. What is it for P2PKH transactions?

Answer (score 2):

There are no "addresses" in protocol. There are only "output scripts". The address is only human-readable representation of script which matches the "output script".

The output script for bare multisig transaction is [m] + [hash1] + [hash2] + ... + [hashN] + [n]

And all of these parts are significant. There is no "classic" representation of such address yet.

bc.i uses the form of **(Escrow X of X1 X2 X3)** (where Xn is standard p2pkh address) but you may use your own.

Comment: So bare multisig transactions do not have "addresses"?